# Special characters with underscore (regex in postgres)

Tags: regex, postgresql

How to recognize with regex pattern including underscore in Postgres?

This is my actual regex:

```
[^\w]+
```

It matches characters fine, problem is with underscore. When I call function with that regex, for instance:

```
select regexp_replace('hello_world!', '[^\w]+', ' ', 'g')
```

I am expecting `hello world`. How to match underscore as well?

Comment: Result 'hello world'? You meant to *remove*  '!' but *replace* '_'? Or you expect 'hello world ' - with a dangling space?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `\w` matches underscores, too, and when you use it in a negated character class, the pattern does not match the `_` chars. You may check the [class-shorthand escape table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CLASS-SHORTHAND-ESCAPES-TABLE):

> `\w`   `[[:alnum:]_]` (note underscore is included)

To remove all chars other than alphanumeric you may take out the `_` and use

```
select regexp_replace('hello_world!', '[^[:alnum:]]+', ' ', 'g')
```

Here, `[^[:alnum:]]+` matches one or more (`+`) consecutive chars other than (`[^...]` is a negated bracket expression) letters and digits (`[:alnum:]` POSIX character class matches letters and digits).

[image]

Well, you might as well use `(?:\W|_)+`. Unfortunately, a common regex construct like `[\W_]+` won't work because `\W` (and other negated shorthands like `\S` and `\D` are illegal inside bracket expressions. More details are available in the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CLASS-SHORTHAND-ESCAPES-TABLE):

> Within bracket expressions, `\d`, `\s`, and `\w` lose their outer brackets, and `\D`, `\S`, and `\W` are illegal. (So, for example, `[a-c\d]` is equivalent to `[a-c[:digit:]]`. Also, `[a-c\D]`, which is equivalent to `[a-c^[:digit:]]`, is illegal.)

To get rid of resulting trailing/leading spaces you may use `trim`:

```
select trim(regexp_replace('hello_world!', '[^[:alnum:]]+', ' ', 'g'))
```

Comment: [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CLASS-SHORTHAND-ESCAPES-TABLE) *"Within bracket expressions, `\d`, `\s`, and `\w` lose their outer brackets, and `\D`, `\S`, and `\W` are illegal."* That's why `[\W_]+` does not work.

Comment: One can use `[^a-zA-Z0-9]+` instead of `[^[:alnum:]]+` depending on preference (length is the same).

Comment: Ok, I see why I misunderstood that manual line. I will add to the answer.